# Running more than 30 IE8 sessions with -nomerge

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I am trying to load test a web app that uses cookies to track sessions by using the -nomerge switch on IE8 to allow multiple distinct sessions on a single machine. I want to run about 50 sessions on a single box but IE stops starting more sessions at approximately 30 (it varies per machine, sometimes 28 or 29 but I've not seen more than 30).

This also appears to be a per user issue - I can have more sessions on a single machine if I start 30 under one user, switch to a different user and start more sessions.

Is there a way I can increase this limit so that a single user can launch more sessions?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum you seem to have hit may be in Windows rather than in IE.

From [Configure the max limit for concurrent TCP connections](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html) :

> To keep the TCP/IP stack from taking
>   all resources on the computer, there
>   are different parameters that control
>   how many connections it can handle.

The article describes how to modify some of these parameters. But if you can't find them all, the solution might be to use a virtual machine or another computer in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is it. The article you linked to suggests the limit is in thousands (or at least hundreds) which is significantly more than 30! Plus the fact that it is per logged in user suggests I'm not hitting any fundamental OS limit.

Comment: The article was just an example. Many of the limits in Windows are unknown.